# how to update specific row

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

`p` its object of person.

```
p.setFname(etname.getText().toString());

p.setLname(etfname.getText().toString());

p.setPassword(etpass.getText().toString());

p.setBirthday(spinnerDay.getSelectedItem().toString() + "/"
+spinnerMonth.getSelectedItem().toString() + "/" + spinnerYear.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

now how am I put the new name and pass and everything insted of what i had in the database before.

this is my database:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "all_users";
    public  static final String NAME = "name";
    public  static final String FNAME = "fname";
    public  static final String EMAIL = "email";
    public  static final String PASS = "pass";
    public  static final String BDAY = "bday";
    public  static final String GENDER = "gender";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String SQL_Create="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (";
        SQL_Create+=NAME+" TEXT, ";
        SQL_Create+=FNAME+" TEXT, ";
        SQL_Create+=EMAIL+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, ";
        SQL_Create+=PASS+" TEXT, ";
        SQL_Create+=BDAY+" TEXT, ";
        SQL_Create+=GENDER+" TEXT); ";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_Create);
```

Comment: Well the email field is your primary key so: `UPDATE all_users SET name='aaa', pass='bbb' WHERE email='aaaa@bbbb.com`'

Answer (score -1):

Try with this for updating name and password i.e.:

```
ContentValues vContentValues = new ContentValues();
vContentValues.put("NAME", "coral1235");
vContentValues.put("PASS", "1234");
sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, vContentValues, null, null)
```

**EDIT:** if you wanna replace specific row, you must write the conditions. Replace last row with this for row where email is i.e. coral1235@mail.com:

```
sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME, vContentValues, EMAIL + "=?" , new String[]{"coral1235@mail.com"});
```

Comment: you need to pass `whereClause` and `whereArgs` this is wrong, this will update all records in table.

Comment: yeah well I don't see any condition requested in question post so null it is. Anyway,  answer is updated with condition for email

Comment: what about the title of the question "how to update **specific** row"